# Encrypt Windows remote desktop session, when using Microsoft Remote Desktop for Mac as the host client

Tags: remote-desktop

How can i set encryption of the traffic sent between the host / client and visa versa in a Windows remote desktop session, when using Microsoft Remote Desktop for Mac as the client ?

In the setup where looking at using :

- CLIENT : Remote Desktop for Mac v 10.x (latest at time of writing)
- HOST : W10 pro (latest at time of writing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft RDP client for macOS (and IOS) always uses the highest encryption level supported by the OS on the server side. (It will fall back to no encryption if the server can't do encryption, which should normally never be the case.)

So there is no need to enable it yourself (and there is no way to manually do it as far as I know). It is always on.

Comment: Thanks @tonny, So does that mean that i would have to set the encryption on the host windows machine (running w10 pro) or when the host and client initially communicate do they default between them to strongest available ? If so is there a way to see what encryption is being used ?

Comment: @sam Encryption on the Windows side is always on (since NT4 or WIn2000, not sure). You can downgrade the encryption by changing registry settings or using the group-policy editor. Not something the average user will ever do. Another thing is NLA which you can enable in the Remote Settings control panel. Strictly speaking not encryption but a more secure way of logging in to the remote system. The current Microsoft RDP client for macOS is compatible with this. The older RDP client (prior to 2017 if I recall correctly) wasn't.